# Move/copy folders by groups

Tags: unix

I have a folder containing subfolders named; *_1, *_2,  *_3, *_4  . . .  *_1000.
Then there is another set of folders named: Destination_folder1, Destination_folder2, Destination_folder3, ....Destination_folder10. 
I would like to move (or copy) the subfolders by groups of 100 in Destination_folders* so that: the Destination_folder1 will contain subfolders *_1: *_100; Destination_folder2 will contain subfolders *_101: *_200 and so on and so forh. I tried to use:

> ```
>   for i in {1..100}    
>   do     
>   cp -r *_$((i)) Destination_folder$i/     
>   done
> ```

but unfortunately folders are not copied by groups, but instead they are copied 
individually. Can anyone help me please?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second loop (remove the word echo when you are happy):

```
for i in {1..10}; do
        for j in {1..100}; do
                (( dir = 100 * (i - 1) + j ))
                echo cp -r *_$((dir)) Destination_folder${i}/
        done
done
```

Comment: Dear Walter, thank you very much for your help but  the Destination_folder*s are empty.

Comment: Did you remove `echo` in the line `echo cp -r *_$((dir)) Destination_folder${i}/`?

Comment: Not unfortunately..So this is the problem I suppose